# Connecting Elasticsearch to Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to display the iris data in kibana by connecting to elasticsearch and creating an index called "iris" in R. I am taking the following steps:

1. Execute elasticsearch 5.5.3 batch file (localhost:9200 displays results on web)
2. Run the following code in R (connects and displays the iris search result successfully)

   **library(elasticsearchr)

   es<- elastic("http://localhost:9200", "iris", "data")

   es %index% iris

   for_everything <- query('{
   "match_all": {}
   }')

   es %search% for_everything**
3. Run Kibana 5.5.3 batch file (checked yml file which says *#elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"*)

However, Kibana can't search the index "iris" as shown below:[image]

I tried running the logstash 5.5.3 batchfile before step 3, but it generated an error message on command prompt and closed. Another weird thing is that I don't see any index created on localhost:9200 on web, while searching for index in R shows results. Plus, below is the message I get when I start in step 1.
[image: elastic message]
FYI, result of **http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices**
[image: cat_indices]
[image: _search?pretty]
This is a snapshot of my kibana management > index pattern page.
[image: index_pattern]

Comment: can you search on iris index with elasticsearch search API? like: localhost:9200/iris/_search?pretty.

Comment: can you share result of /_cat/indices

Comment: @hamidbayat I edited the image in the post. I tried adding a new index named iris_210508, which seems like it did as shown in /_cat/indices. The other indices were created years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `index pattern` to kibana via management -> kibana -> index patterns.

at the moment you are searching "iris" word on none of your index. also i think you must change your search phrase.